# How to customize D3 Chart labels

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, d3.js

I have a custom chart I am trying to put together. The chart will be responsive and it is required to look like the following.

[image: REQUIRED CHART]

I am unsure of how to do the outer grey ticks. The working code I have does not display correctly.

Also any tips on the labels would e great.

Currently it looks like this.
[image]
[WORKING DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-d3-pie-chart-forked-omrw2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a React user, and never heard of PieHooks etc but thanks to your working demo I could fiddle about and see that the tick values aren't set at absolute values around the circle but offset to the last tick - like the 'data' in fact.

e.g. This gives 36 evenly spaced ticks (though why they start slightly off-vertical I don't know):

```
  for (let i = 0; i < 36; i += 1) {
      dataTicks.push({value: 1});
  }
```

Hope that's some help